# Problems when loading Assemblies in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, .net-assembly

I'm currently building a powershell transfer script that uses WinSCP assembly to upload files. I have defined a class in which I'm initializing things like the WinSCP.SessionOptions etc. These types are defined in the WinSCPnet.dll. At the beginning of my script I'm importing the assembly with

```
Add-Type -Path <Path-to-assembly.dll>
```

Later in my class definition I have a variable like this that is not yet initialized

```
[WinSCP.SessionOptions]$Script:SessionOptions
```

When I try to run the script I always get "Type not found" error referencing to the line where I'm declaring the uninitialized variable.

This problem  is not limited to the WinSCP assemblies. I'm also getting it when I call a static method no matter if it's a system or a custom assembly.

What can I do to solve that?

Thanks in advance.